# Why Representation of Clifford algebra are constant for an orthonormal frame?

Tags: manifolds, clifford-algebras, tangent-bundle, spin-geometry

Let $e_\alpha$ be a basis of the tangent bundle $TM$ and $ \rho: T_x M \rightarrow \operatorname{End}\left( W\right)$ a representation of a Clifford algebra.

In this text [Field theory from a bundle point of view](https://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/lectures.pdf)
 by Laurent Claessens he claims at page 122 that if the frame $e_\alpha$ are orthonormal everywhere, then we have the matricial equality
$$
\rho\left(\left(e_\alpha\right)_x\right)_{i j}=\rho\left(v_\alpha\right)_{i j}
$$
where  $v_\alpha$ is a basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Why this claim is true?

Comment: Note that the representation is not any Clifford representation, but a representation on a subbundle of $TM$